# Coordinates on basemap seems to be at 0,0

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot some longitudal and latitudal coordinates on a map with `basemap`. The code I am running is:

```
m = Basemap(projection='merc', resolution='i',
            llcrnrlat=min_lat - 3, urcrnrlat=max_lat + 3,
            llcrnrlon=min_long - 3, urcrnrlon=max_long + 3)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color="#FFDDCC", lake_color='#DDEEFF')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#DDEEFF')
m.drawcountries(linewidth=1)
for coordinates in locations:
    m.scatter(coordinates[1], coordinates[0], marker='D', color='m')

plt.show()
```

where:

```
min_lat, min_long, max_lat, max_long = 48.9810946, -0.014840257753543178, 60.448137, 24.9362469
```

and the coordinates in this setup, i.e. `locations` (that is plotted via the `for loop`) are these six:

```
[55.663457, 12.34772]
[53.5797869, 10.0131747]
[53.549816899999996, 10.048393278279384]
[52.3353336, 4.9294416]
[51.5118813, -0.0010296]
[51.5118813, -0.0010296]
```

The result is:

[image]

and as you may be able to see there are some purple in the lower-left corner, which I'm guessing is all the points wrapped up in the same point.

I have tried to make the map bigger, but that results in the same, and I also tried to switch between `m.scatter(coordinates[1], coordinates[0], marker='D', color='m')` and `m.scatter(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], marker='D', color='m')` with the same result.

What am I doing wrong here? (and yes, this is my first time with `basemap`, so bear with me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearange your date and call your Basemap object `m()` to calculate the map projection coordinates.

```
lons = [12.34772, 10.0131747, 10.048393278279384, 4.9294416, -0.0010296, -0.0010296]
lats = [55.663457, 53.5797869, 53.549816899999996, 52.3353336, 51.5118813, 51.5118813]

x, y = m(lons, lats)

m.scatter(x, y, marker='D',color='m')
```

[Here](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapcoords.html) is a tutorial.